# Custom permission return always true, django

Tags: python, django

Sorry for my english. Now i learning django rest and i try create custom permisssion for user. Fox example permission: "big" and "small".

My user model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar/users', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("big", "this is big boy"),
            ("small", "this is small"),
        )
```

then i added permission to user something like this:

```
permission = Permission.objects.get(name='big')
        user.user_permissions.add(permission)
        user.save()
```

created custom class, it class check permission:

```
class IsBigBoy(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.has_perm('users.big')
```

and in view i create test class for check my custom permission

```
class MySuperTestRequest(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, custom_permissions.IsBigBoy)
    serializer_class = CreateSomethingSerializer

    def post(self, 
        return Response({"detail": "good"}, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Problem:**

```
return request.user.has_perm('users.big')
```

it code always return `true`

Comment: If the logged-in user is a superuser, then `has_perm` will *always* return `True`. What is the name of the app that contains the `User` model?

Comment: @Alasdair oooo, thanks for your answer i try do it from superuser. I will check it. App call `users`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

may be you need user `has_perms()` for your logic, and don't forget if user is_superuser he has all permissions.